# React Native : Update context api values in jest unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, react-native, jestjs, react-context, react-native-testing-library

I am writing unit tests for validations of a react native form with few text inputs and a custom dropdown field. I am using `jest` with `react-native-testing-library`. The form is validated on submit btn press. The form values are saved to, and accessed from the context (which uses useReducer() hook).

I could not simulate input-ing value to the `Dropdown` field, so to skip over it, I wanted to set the context value of the field by dispatching a random valid value to the context, wrapped with in `act()`, so that the validation doesnot stop there and continue to validate the next `TextInput`.

But, when I log the context value, it still stays as before, and the validation halts with the previous fields.

**ContextProvider.js**

```
export function FormContextProvider({children}){
  const [formValues, dispatchFormValues] = useReducer(
    formValuesReducer,
    individualFormInitialState
  );

  return <FormContext.Provider value={formValues,dispatchFormValues}> 
  {children}</FormContext.Provider>

}


function formValuesReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FIELD_VALUE":
      return { ...state, ...action.payload };  
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**FormComponent.js**

```
export default class FormComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
  const formContext = useContext();
  const [t1Err, setT1Err] = useState("");
  const [t2Err, t2Err] = useState("");
  const [dpErr, dpErr] = useState("");

  const validateAndSubmit = ()=>{
   //some validations...

  }

  return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
        value="whatever"
        onChange={(val)=>formContext.dispatch({
          type:"FORM_VALUE",
          payload:{t1:val}
        })}
        ></TextInput>
      <DropdownSelect 
        some={props}
        onChange={(val)=>formContext.dispatch({
          type:"FORM_VALUE",
          payload:{dp:val}
        })}
       value={formContext.formValues.dp}
     />
     <TextInput
        value="whatever"
        onChange={()=>formContext.dispatch({
          type:"FORM_VALUE",
          payload:{t2:val}
        })}
        ></TextInput>
      {t2Err ? <InputError>{"This field is mandatory"}</InputError>:<></>}
      <Button onPress={validateAndSubmit}></Button>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**FormComponent.test.js**

```
   const form = (
    <FormContextProvider>
      <FormContext.Consumer>
        {props => {
          return (
            <Text testID="context_exposer" {...props}>
              Exposes Context
            </Text>
          );
        }}
      </FormContext.Consumer>
      <FormComponent navigation={navigation} />
    </FormContextProvider>
   );

    //expose the context for tests
    const {
     dispatchFormValues,
     formValues
    } = form.getByTestId("context_exposer").props;


   describe("form validations",()=>{

     it("t2 validations",done=>{

        fireEvent.changeText(t1, "valid input text");
        act(
          ()=>dispatchFormValues({
            type: "FIELD_VALUE",
            payload: { dp: 200 }
          })
        );
        console.log("formValues", formValues.dp);/* *** still logs old values *** */
        fireEvent.press(submitBtn);
        //t2 input is empty and required, so on submitbtnPress, should show an error msg.
        const t2Err = t2Input.findByType(InputError); 

        expect(t2Err).not.toBeNull();//test fails since no errorMsg element is showing.
        done();

   });


  })
```

So, my question is, why does not the context update? Is this wrong way to update the context?

*Note:* I am not mocking the context, and would prefer this way, to use the actual context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was some mistake I made, not any quirk with the testing libraries.

1. The context was updating, Its just that the global variable I was using had the old values, and to get the updated context value, I had to access the context again like `form.getByTestId("context_exposer").props`.`formValues`
2. I was inputting invalid text to the first text input("valid input text"/* not valid :) */), halting the validation to there itself.

Thank you for your time.